# Adding values to pandas dataframe in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to iteratively add values to rows and columns through loops. If i increase the number of rolls in this case, loop should add new 1000 values to columns for each specific number of rolls creating new rows each with 1000 columns. However, I am getting the error "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

```
import random
import pandas as pd
A = [2,6,7]
B = [1,5,9]
C = [3,4,8]
a = pd.DataFrame(); b = pd.DataFrame()
N = 1000
rolls = -1
while rolls != 0:
    rolls += 1
    for i in range(N):
        a.at[rolls,i] = [random.choice(A)]
        b.at[rolls,i] = [random.choice(B)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Set scalar instead one element list:

```
a.at[rolls,i] = random.choice(A)
b.at[rolls,i] = random.choice(B)
```